# How do I get just the base table rows when using Table-per-Type with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have the following tables mapped in Entity Framework 4.2 as table-per-type.

```
Gear (ID, Name, Description) // base table
Weapon (ID, Damage, Bonus) // FK to Gear table.
Armor (ID, Kinetic, Energy) // FK to Gear table.
```

I can get the weapons and gear separately as such:

```
var weapons = db.Gear.OfType<Weapon>(); // Gets just weapons.
var armor = db.Gear.OfType<Armor>(); // Gets just armor.
```

but I can't figure out how to get just the base rows. I was hoping something like this would work but it still gets all of them.

```
var basicGear = db.Gear.OfType<Gear>();
```

Comment: All the Weapons and Armour are Gear as well, so what's wrong with getting all of the rows? Or do you mean you want all the rows that aren't specifically Weapons or Armour?

Comment: I'd like to get all gear that isn't a weapon or piece of armor.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var basicGear = db.Gear.Where(g => !(g is Weapon || g is Armor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all the rows that aren't specifically Weapons or Armour. Generally, I would say you could try using the [Except method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

```
var weapons = db.Gear.OfType<Weapon>(); // Gets just weapons.
var armor = db.Gear.OfType<Armor>(); // Gets just armor.
var allOtherStuff = db.Gear.Except(weapons).Except(armor);
```

Or even

```
var allOtherStuff = db.Gear.Except(weapons.Union(armor));
```

However, I'm not aware if Except has a translation to SQL within the Entity Framework (based on [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667266/how-do-i-make-an-except-linq-to-entities-query) on here they suggest it might not but this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340913.aspx) would suggest it might).